# MongoDB Atlas authentication failed on Python

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have deployed this Python app on Heroku and i want it to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. I used my string to connect to the cluster, but for some reason i keep getting `raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth Authentication failed.` I checked twice and both the user and the password are correct. Any idea on why this is happening?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time
import random
import time
import datetime


client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://USER:<MYPASSWORD>@test-2liju.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true')

db = client.one

mycol = client["tst"]


while True:


    test = int(random.randrange(-99999990,90000000,1))

    dic = {"num": test}

    result = db.tst.insert_one(dic)


    print(test)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 15):

Stupid error, i had to type `MYPASSWORD` instead of `<MYPASSWORD>`, without the `<>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any special char in password, like '+' or '='.

I use OpenSSL to generate a password like u4wY9AOwnOLMY+h9EQ==. Came across bad auth Authentication failed.

After using MongoDB Compass it told me don't use special char, so I remove those and use like 'u4wY9AOwnOLMYh9EQ'.

Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

check the compatibility of the version of the Python driver you choose from the Mongodb Atlas Connections. versions above 3.4 are not supported by mongoengine flask